# How can I create a Gaussian blur that doesn't effect the edges? Adobe Fireworks

Tags: adobe-fireworks, blur

I'm trying to use a Gaussian blur on an image, but I don't want it to effect the edges of the image. How can I do this? I'm using Adobe Fireworks.

Here's the image I am using:
[image: the image]

And here's what I did:
[image: what I did]

See how the Gaussian blur effects the edges? I don't want that.

I'm trying to create an effect like this:
[image: desired effect]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a selection before applying the blur...

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you want soft edges on the blurred area, draw your marquee and set the edge to feather before selecting a blur radius. .

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid editing the source image itself but create the same effect, add a grayscale mask by grouping the image with a vector object (using rectangle tool) that is filled white and placed on top.